# pandas convert from datetime to integer timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, datetime-conversion

Considering a pandas dataframe in python having a column named `time` of type integer, I can convert it to a `datetime` format with the following instruction.

```
df['time'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
```

so now the column has entries like: `2019-01-15 13:25:43`.

What is the command to revert the string to an integer timestamp value (representing the number of seconds elapsed from `1970-01-01 00:00:00`)?

I checked `pandas.Timestamp` but could not find a conversion utility and I was not able to use `pandas.to_timedelta` for this.

Is there any utility for this conversion?

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/q/4548684/9754169

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can typecast to int using `astype(int)` and divide it by `10**9` to get the number of seconds to the unix epoch start.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('2019-01-15 13:25:43')]})
df_unix_sec = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).astype(int)/ 10**9
print(df_unix_sec)
```

Comment: This would be fantastic but it's not giving the expected result: I tried the following lines:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('2019-01-15 13:25:43')]})`

`df['time'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s',origin='unix')`

It is not returning any error but I cannot see any change in the column

Comment: Psst, casting to int is in my answer ;-)

Comment: @FrancescoBoi actually initially I misunderstood the `to_datetime` parameters. Have a look I also asked a question on SO here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313463/pandas-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-seconds. So if you cast it to `int` then it'll work for you :)

Comment: @coldspeed yes sir, I've already mentioned that on my previous comment. So `df_unix_sec = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).astype(int)` will work here

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant my answer on this question as well.

Comment: Well, if you can just add you need to divide by 10 ** 9 to get a nix timestamp, I'll just delete my answer then.

Comment: Yes sir @coldspeed fixed that

Comment: Since I was getting a float type after dividing by `10**9` in my opinion is better to add another cast: `res = (pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').astype(int)/10**9).astype(int)`

Comment: @FrancescoBoi Yes Agreed. :)

Answer (score 39):

The easiest way is to use `.value`

```
pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01').value
```

If you want to apply it to the whole column, just use `.apply`:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.value)
```

Comment: `.astype(int)` was faster for my dask.compute():


`df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.value, meta=(col, int))  # 1.0s`
vs
`df[col] = df[col].astype(int)  # 0.8s`

Answer (score 9):

Use `.dt.total_seconds()` on a `timedelta64`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('2019-01-15 13:25:43')]})

# pd.to_timedelta(df.time).dt.total_seconds() # Is deprecated
(df.time - pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01')).dt.total_seconds()
```

#### Output

```
0    1.547559e+09
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 9):

One can also use `.view(...)`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('2019-01-15 13:25:43')]})
df_unix_sec = pd.to_datetime(df['time']).view(int) // 10 ** 9
print(df_unix_sec)
```

Casting with `.astype(int)`, recommended above, is [deprecated in pandas 1.3.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html), and throws a warning:

```
FutureWarning: casting datetime64[ns] values to int64 with .astype(...) is deprecated and will raise in a future version. Use .view(...) instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Ignacio recommends, this is what I am using to cast to integer:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.value)
```

Then, to get it back:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(pd.Timestamp)
```