# pandas datetime to unix timestamp seconds

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

From the official documentation of [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) we can say,

> unit : string, default ‘ns’
>
> unit of the arg (D,s,ms,us,ns) denote the unit, which is an integer or
> float number. This will be based off the origin. **Example, with
> unit=’ms’ and origin=’unix’ (the default), this would calculate the
> number of milliseconds to the unix epoch start.**

So when I try like this way,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [pd.to_datetime('2019-01-15 13:25:43')]})
df_unix_sec = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms', origin='unix')
print(df)
print(df_unix_sec)

                 time
0   2019-01-15 13:25:43
0   2019-01-15 13:25:43
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Output is not changing for the latter one. Every time it is showing the datetime value not  number of milliseconds to the unix epoch start for the 2nd one. Why is that? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what the argument is for. The purpose of `origin='unix'` is to convert an integer timestamp *to* `datetime`, not the other way.

```
pd.to_datetime(1.547559e+09, unit='s', origin='unix') 
# Timestamp('2019-01-15 13:30:00')
```

Here are some options:

#### Option 1: integer division

Conversely, you can get the timestamp by converting to integer (to get nanoseconds) and divide by 10<sup>9</sup>.

```
pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-15 13:30:00']).astype(int) / 10**9
# Float64Index([1547559000.0], dtype='float64')
```

Pros:

- super fast

Cons:

- makes assumptions about how pandas internally stores dates

---

#### Option 2: recommended by pandas

[Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#from-timestamps-to-epoch) recommend using the following method:

```
# create test data
dates = pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-15 13:30:00'])

# calculate unix datetime
(dates - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta('1s')

[out]:
Int64Index([1547559000], dtype='int64')
```

Pros:

- "idiomatic", recommended by the library

Cons:

- unweildy
- not as performant as integer division

---

#### Option 3: `pd.Timestamp`

If you have a single date string, you can use `pd.Timestamp` as shown in the other answer:

```
pd.Timestamp('2019-01-15 13:30:00').timestamp()
# 1547559000.0
```

If you have to cooerce multiple datetimes (where `pd.to_datetime` is your only option), you can initialize and map:

```
pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-15 13:30:00']).map(pd.Timestamp.timestamp)
# Float64Index([1547559000.0], dtype='float64')
```

Pros:

- best method for a single datetime string
- easy to remember

Cons:

- not as performant as integer division

Comment: Note that Pandas now recommends `.view()` instead of `.astype()` for method 1,  This method works with a (timezone-aware) `DateTimeIndex` array as well, **unless** daylight-savings time starts or ends in that time span.  In that case, I get `TypeError: Cannot change data-type for object array.`  Conversion to UTC fixes this.

Comment: In option 1) you may need to cast `astype("int64")`. With `astype(int)` I am getting `TypeError: Converting from datetime64[ns] to int32 is not supported. Do obj.astype('int64').astype(dtype) instead`

Comment: Regarding option 2: If you want to convert a **timezone-aware** datetime to a Unix timestamp, you will get an error "TypeError: Cannot subtract tz-naive and tz-aware datetime-like objects". The solution is to use `(dates - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01", tz='UTC')) // pd.Timedelta("1s")`

Answer (score 29):

You can use [timestamp() method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.timestamp.html) which returns POSIX timestamp as float:

```
pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01').timestamp()

[Out]:
1617235200.0

pd.Timestamp('2021-04-01 00:02:35.234').timestamp()

[Out]:
1617235355.234
```

Answer (score 3):

`value` attribute of the pandas Timestamp holds the unix epoch. This value is in nanoseconds. So you can convert to ms or us by diving by 1e3 or 1e6. Check the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
date_1 = pd.to_datetime('2020-07-18 18:50:00')
print(date_1.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you calculate the difference between two datetimes, the dtype of the difference is `timedelta64[ns]` by default (`ns` in brackets). By changing `[ns]` into `[ms]`, `[s]`, `[m]` etc as you cast the output to a new `timedelta64` object, you can convert the difference into milliseconds, seconds, minutes etc.

For example, to find the number of seconds passed since Unix epoch, subtract datetimes and change dtype.

```py
df_unix_sec = (df['time'] - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

N.B. Oftentimes, the differences are very large numbers, so if you want them as integers, use `astype('int64')` (NOT `astype(int)`).

```py
df_unix_sec = (df['time'] - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')).astype('timedelta64[s]').astype('int64')
```

For OP's example, this would yield,

```
0    1547472343
Name: time, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -2):

In case you are accessing a particular `datetime64` object from the dataframe, chances are that pandas will return a `Timestamp` object which is essentially how pandas stores `datetime64` objects.

You can use `pd.Timestamp.to_datetime64()` method of the `pd.Timestamp` object to convert it to `numpy.datetime64` object with `ns` precision.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for your time in answering this question. Please read the question of the OP carefully. Does your solution answer the question better/different than the accepted answer?