# Python Why pd.to_datetime returning timestamp format?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

In Python I'm trying to format my date column in a dataframe to float object format. I end up getting Timestamp format instead.

In:

```
X = []

for row in data:
   date = pd.to_datetime(row[0], format='%Y/%m/%d')
   X.append(date)

print(X)
```

Out:

```
[Timestamp('2008-01-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2009-01-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2010-01-04 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2011-01-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2012-01-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2013-12-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2014-12-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-01-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2016-01-04 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2017-01-03 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2018-01-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-01-02 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-01-02 00:00:00')]
```

How can I change to float object instead of Timestamp? Should I be using datetime.strptime instead?

Comment: What does your original data look like?

Comment: I put the values of my data into a list. So data looks like this: ````[['2007-01-03',
  70.57,
  0.0,
  70.57,
  89.22,
  0.0,
  89.22,
  100.0,
  0.0,
  100.0,
  63.58,
  24.27],
 ['2008-01-02',
  72.6,
  1.2970000000000002,
  73.50789999999999,
  93.25,
  3.4570000000000003,
  95.6699,
  105.66,
  3.2920000000000003,
  107.9644,
  83.56,
  32.06]]````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need dates in numeric format, use:

```py
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020/03/08', '%Y/%m/%d')
timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
```

Dates will be displayed as UNIX timestamps (float type)

Edit: if you want to use pandas, see also [pandas datetime to unix timestamp seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313463/pandas-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-seconds)

Comment: Just to clarify, does this return float, or time since epoch?

Comment: A float, representing the time since epoch

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to loop over the entire dataframe to convert the `datetime` to `float` there is a better way to accomplish this,

**Try this:**

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%Y/%m/%d").astype("datetime64").astype(int).astype(float)
```

Comment: I get the error ````'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'astype'````