# pandas datetime string with milliseconds to unix timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I got a dataframe with one column containing the date-time data with milli seconds precision.  How can I convert it to unix timestamp ?

My data is of the form

```
0         2017-05-16 00:00:00.008
1         2017-05-16 00:00:00.272
2         2017-05-16 00:00:01.551
3         2017-05-16 00:00:01.813
4         2017-05-16 00:00:03.091
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313463/pandas-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-seconds

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to convert each entry into a timestamp:

```
from datetime import datetime

t = '2017-05-16 00:00:00.008'
ts = datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").timestamp()

print(ts)  # 1494885600.008
```

if your column name is `d` then you can convert each value into a unix timestamp as follows:

```
df['d'] = df['d'].apply(lambda t: datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").timestamp())
```