# Converting Python datetime.timedelta object in order to be read by Recharts

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to make basic plots in Recharts (using React) and Flask (using the Formula1 API). The data I get in Flask is originally a `datetime.timedelta`  object and I'm having trouble sending it over to React. To send the data, it needs to be JSON serializable, so I tried converting it to:

- a string (of the `timedelta` object)
- an integer (`timedelta` converted to nanoseconds)

but I'm not sure how to unpack these in React.

Here are the 2 data formats I tried.

```
>>> data_str = [{
     "LapNumber": '0',
     "44": "0 days 00:01:27.440000",
     "6": "0 days 00:01:27.313000"},
    {"name": '1',
     "44": "0 days 00:01:28.982000",
     "6":  "0 days 00:01:27.504000"
     }]
>>> data_int = [{
         "LapNumber": '0',
         "44": 87440000000,
         "6": 87313000000},
        {"LapNumber": '1',
         "44": 88982000000,
         "6":  87504000000
         }]
```

app.py

```
@app.route('/api/lap_number_time')
def getChartData():
    # data = list of dictionaries in one of the formats shown above
    return jsonify(data)
```

App.js

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/lap_number_time")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("first chart data is", data)
                setCurrentChartData(data)
            })
    }, [])

...
<LineChart width={400} height={400} data={currentChartData}>
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="14" stroke="#8884d8" />
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="ham" stroke="#82ca9d" />
    <Line type="monotone" dataKey="6" stroke="#1a5d57" />
    <XAxis dataKey="LapNumber"/>
    <YAxis />
    <Legend />
</LineChart>
```

My questions are:

1. Can I transfer the `timedelta` object to Recharts and plot it there (since integer conversion for each data point would take a long time)?
2. If not, I got Recharts to successfully plot when its in integer format. But, I need help displaying it in `[%min:%sec:%millisec]` format in Recharts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest here you use either of these methods [pandas datetime to unix timestamp seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313463/pandas-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-seconds) and convert datetime to unix timestamp and send it over to React.

Then take a look at this approach by [Dennis Sandmark](https://github.com/dsandmark)

https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/956#issuecomment-339279600