# How to convert string date column to timestamp in a new column in Python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following example dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': ["2022-05-16T12:31:00Z", "2021-01-11T11:32:00Z"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    col1
0   2022-05-16T12:31:00Z
1   2021-01-11T11:32:00Z
```

I need a second column (say **col2**) which will have the corresponding timestamp value for each col1 date string value from **col1**.

How can I do that without using a for loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas datetime to unix timestamp seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313463/pandas-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-seconds)

Comment: @FObersteiner Thank you for your comment. It includes similar solutions to the ones I got here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': ["2022-05-16T12:31:00Z", "2021-01-11T11:32:00Z"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])
df['col2'] = df.col2.values.astype(np.int64) // 10 ** 9

df
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `to_datetime`

```
df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])
df
Out[614]: 
                   col1                      col2
0  2022-05-16T12:31:00Z 2022-05-16 12:31:00+00:00
1  2021-01-11T11:32:00Z 2021-01-11 11:32:00+00:00
```

Update

```
st = pd.to_datetime('1970-01-01T00:00:00Z')
df['unix'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['col1'])- st).dt.total_seconds()
Out[632]: 
0    1.652704e+09
1    1.610365e+09
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need the timestamp value i.e. 1652706735, not the date object. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @edn check the update

Comment: Thank you for the update! Can I somehow use the timetuple() function on the column? I get the "'Series' object has no attribute 'timetuple'" error when I try it.