# Remove days and date from datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using pandas datetime for some timeseries data I am using.  But the data I am using only really needs the seconds portion of datetime as I am working with data that is highly temporally detailed and the date is not useful information.  Is there a way to create indices only based on the time in seconds (sampled at 2500Hz) without the date or is that required in datetime?

Comment: I recommend leaving the timestamp data alone.  If you need to resample the data at a different frequency it makes it much more accurate. It does not need to be your index.

Comment: please provide a sample df

Comment: you can convert pandas datetime [to unix time like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54313463/10197418), however I'm not sure if datetime is the right data type in the first place (x-y problem?) if you "only need the seconds portion"

Comment: Date time has useful functions if you need to interpolate data.  Creating an index to relfect the time has major issues.