# How to create a pandas dataframe using a list of 'epoch dates' into '%Y-%m-%d %s:%m:%f%z' format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

My objective is to create the following pandas dataframe (with the 'date_time' column in **'%Y-%m-%d %s:%m:%f%z'** format):

```
     batt_no                  date_time
3          4  2019-09-19 20:59:06+00:00
4          5  2019-09-19 23:44:07+00:00
5          6  2019-09-20 00:44:06+00:00
6          7  2019-09-20 01:14:06+00:00
```

But the constraint is that I don't want to first create a dataframe as follows and then convert the 'date_time' column into the above format.

```
     batt_no   date_time
3          4  1568926746
4          5  1568936647
5          6  1568940246
6          7  1568942046
```

I need to directly create it by converting two lists of values into the desired dataframe.

The following is what I've tried but I get an error
(please note: the 'date_time' values are in epoch format which I need to specify but have them converted into the '%Y-%m-%d %s:%m:%f%z' format):

```
pd.DataFrame({'batt_volt':[4,5,6,7],
              'date_time':[1568926746,1568936647,1568940246,1568942046].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %s:%m:%f%z')}, index=[3,4,5,6])
```

Can anyone please help?

Edit Note: My question is different from the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313463/pandas-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-seconds).
The question there deals with conversion of a single value of pandas datetime to unix timestamp. Mine's different because:

1. My timestamp values are slightly different from any of the types mentioned there
2. I don't need to convert any timestamp value, rather create a full-fledged dataframe having values of the desired timestamp - in a particular manner using lists that I've clearly mentioned in my question.
3. I've clearly stated the way I've attempted the process but requires some modifications in order to run without error, which in no way is similar to the question asked in the aforementioned link.

Hence, my question is definitely different. I'd request to kindly reopen it.

Comment: `df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'], unit='s').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %s:%m:%f%z')`

Comment: @jezrael, as I've mentioned, I do not want to convert the df with dates in epoch format to the desired format. I want to create it directly using the list of values. How do we do the same?

Comment: Likewise. `pd.DataFrame({'batt_volt':[4,5,6,7],
              'date_time': pd.to_datetime([1568926746,1568936647,1568940246,1568942046], unit='s')}, index=[3,4,5,6])`

Comment: @chrslg what you suggested isn't creating the dates with '%Y-%m-%d %s:%m:%f%z' format. It creates something like "2019-09-19 20:59:06". But what I need is "2019-09-19 20:59:06+00:00"

Comment: What I suggest is dates. Format is just how you print them. What you are referring to are strings. Seems a bad idea to store dates as string. But if that is really what you want, just add the `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %s:%m:%f%z' )` at the not (that is your format string. I doubt it is really the one you want since the double `%m` and the `%s` are quite strange here. `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f` seems more realistic)

Comment: So `pd.DataFrame({'batt_volt':[4,5,6,7],               'date_time': pd.to_datetime([1568926746,1568936647,1568940246,1568942046], unit='s').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %s:%m:%f%z')}, index=[3,4,5,6])`. Plus your probable corrections of the format

Comment: @chrslg but even this is resulting in the same output as the previous. The date still looks like "2019-09-19 20:59:06" instead of "2019-09-19 20:59:06+00:00". And yeah, the regular format as you suggested would've been more elegant, however I need to do this in order to compare the values coming from some pre-written code. And there, unfortunately the output contains dates in the latter format.

Comment: Then, if that is the `:+00:00` that bothers you, then you have no good choice. Either adding them explicitly `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f+00:00')`. Or creating timezone aware datetime: `pd.to_datetime([1568926746,1568936647,1568940246,1568942046], unit='s', utc=True).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z')`

Comment: The thing is, there is no timezone in a epoch timestamp. It is just a number. So the timezone, is another information you know. Either you assume that all this is relative to a timezone. And you produce timestamp with no timezone. Or you produce timezone aware timestamps. But the timezone is assumed to be UTC.

Comment: @chrslg ```pd.DataFrame({'batt_volt':[4,5,6,7],               'date_time': pd.to_datetime([1568926746,1568936647,1568940246,1568942046], unit='s', utc=True).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %s:%m:%f%z')}, index=[3,4,5,6])``` Using what you suggested, this does the job! You can consider putting this as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: "But the constraint is that I don't want to first create a dataframe as follows and then convert the 'date_time' column into the above format." Curious, why?

Comment: @levantpied because I'm doing unit testing on a function (which I haven't written) and I'm constrained to make the testing code as concise as possible, especially because I'm using "@pytest.mark.parametrize"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, I put the solution in comment as an answer here.

```py
pd.DataFrame({'batt_volt':[4,5,6,7],               'date_time': pd.to_datetime([1568926746,1568936647,1568940246,1568942046], unit='s', utc=True).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %s:%m:%f%z')}, index=[3,4,5,6])
```

`pd.to_datetime` works with dates, or list of dates, and input dates can be in many formats including epoch int. Keyword `unit` ensure that those ints are interpreted as a number of seconds since 1970-01-01, not of ms, μs, ns, ...

So it is quite easy to use when creating a DataFrame to create directly the list of dates.

Since a list of string, with a specific format was wanted (btw, outside any specific context, I maintain that it is probably preferable to store datetimes, and convert to string only for I/O operations. But I don't know the specific context), we can use `.strftime` on the result, which is of type `DatetimeIndex` when `to_datetime` is called with a list. And `.strftime` also works on those, and then is applied on all datetimes of the list. So we get a list of string of the wanted format.

Last remaining problem was the timezone. And here, there is no perfect solution. Because a simple `int` as those we had at the beginning does not carry a timezone. By default, `to_datetime` creates datetime without a timezone (like those ints are). So they are relative to any timezone the user decide they are.

`to_datetime` can create "timezone aware datetime". But only UTC.  Which is done by keyword arg `utc=True`
With that we get timezone aware datetime, assuming that the ints we provided were in number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00