# Converting to UNIX time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a .csv file that contains:

| created_at | actual_delivery_time |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-02-06 22:24:17 | 2015-02-06 23:27:16 |
| 2015-02-10 21:49:25 | 2015-02-10 22:56:29 |

I want to convert these columns from datetime to UNIX timestamp.

For created_at, I was able to convert:

```
ndf["created_unix"] = pd.to_datetime(ndf["created_at"])
ndf["created_unix"] = (ndf["created_unix"] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta("1s")
```

Which outputted:

| created_unix |
| --- |
| 1423261457 |
| 1423604965 |

This is exactly what I'm looking for, however following the same steps for column actual_delivery_time produces a different result:

```
ndf["actual_unix"] = pd.to_datetime(ndf["actual_delivery_time"])
ndf["actual_unix"] = (ndf["actual_unix"] - pd.Timestamp("1970-01-01")) // pd.Timedelta("1s")
```

This outputs:

| actual_unix |
| --- |
| 1.423265e+09 |
| 1.423609e+09 |

It is readable by the Epoch converter, but it isn't the correct timestamp.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I'm not sure why its producing a different result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas datetime to unix timestamp seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54313463/pandas-datetime-to-unix-timestamp-seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure why its producing a different result.

Consult `ndf.dtypes`.

You are complaining that one column
is of type int, while the other is a float.

Likely one or more actual_delivery_time values
were blank, and pandas represented that with
a floating-point `NaN`.