# pandas convert from datetime.time to integer timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Sadly, the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312802/pandas-convert-from-datetime-to-integer-timestamp) for `datetime.date` do not work for `datetime.time`.

So I implemented an `df.apply()` function, which is doing what I expect:

```
def get_ts_timeonly_float(timeonly):
    if isinstance(timeonly, datetime.time):
        return timeonly.hour * 3600 + timeonly.minute * 60 + timeonly.second
    elif isinstance(timeonly, pd.Timedelta):
        return timeonly.seconds

fn_get_ts_timeonly_pd_timestamp = lambda row: get_ts_timeonly_float(row.ts_timeonly)
col = df.apply(fn_get_ts_timeonly_pd_timestamp, axis=1)
df = df.assign(ts_timeonly_as_ts=col.values)
```

Problem:

> However, this is not yet “blazingly fast.” One reason is that .apply()
>   will try internally to loop over Cython iterators. But in this case,
>   the lambda that you passed isn’t something that can be handled in
>   Cython, so it’s called in Python, which is consequently not all that
>   fast.

[This is a great blog post](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/)

So is there a faster method to convert `datetime.time` into some `int` representation (like `total_seconds` till start of day)? Thanks!

Comment: The use of branching (`if`) pretty much exclude your code from "blazing fast" (i.e. vectorized) operations offered by pandas. How did you get the `time` values in the first place? Try keeping the columns as `pd.Timedelta` so you can use `col.total_seconds()`. Anyhow, some sample input will be helpful here

Comment: You are right with the `if` statement @CodeDifferent. I converted the `datetime.time()` now to `pd.Timedelta` using `pd.to_timedelta(df.ts_timeonly.astype(str))` and removed the if statement. Thanks.