# How to convert timestamp into integer?

Tags: python, types, timestamp, integer

I've got a value that is of the type:

```
'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'
```

but I want to convert it into:

```
'int'
```

Simply using `int()` doesn't work and gives me the following error message:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

Edit: to be clear, I only want the type to change to integral. However I want the number to stay the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas convert from datetime to integer timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312802/pandas-convert-from-datetime-to-integer-timestamp)

Comment: Unfortunately not. If I try to do this, my timeframe value will convert to a different integral number. For reference it goes from 15478 to 741398400000000000. What I want is just that this value get's converted to an integral number, but the number itself doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the class (`pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp`) methods. `pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.timestamp()` returns the timestamp, however it is a `float` instead of an `int`.

Comment: I'm missing something I'm afraid. I'm pretty new to Python just typing this out in either in this way: x.pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.timestamp() or this way: pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.timestamp(x) gives new error messages.